# Table design (html)

Tags: html, html-table

I'm struggling with a design that I have to do, I searched about this implementation but what I found wasn't what I really need, I have this table:

**TABLE 1:**

```
 ----------------------------------------------------------
 | Title1 | Title2  | Title3 | Title 4 | Title 5 | Title6 |
 ----------------------------------------------------------
 |Content1|Content2 |Content3|Content4 |Content5 |Content6|
 ----------------------------------------------------------
```

What I want to do is this:

**TABLE 2:**

```
-------------------------------------
| Title1 | Title2 | Title3 | Title5 |
-------------------------------------
|        |        |Content3|Content5|
|        |        |------------------
|Content1|Content2| Title4 | Title6 |
|        |        -------------------
|        |        |Content4|Content6|
-------------------------------------
```

I'm getting a hard time to do this because every rowspan/colspan example I see is just putting two cells under the same cell Title, like:

**TABLE 3:**

```
-------------------
| Title1 | Title2  |
-------------------|
|Content1|         |
---------| Content3|
|Content2|         |
-------------------|
```

How can I transform Table 1 into Table 2?

Comment: Try http://html-tables.com/ - 4 rows, 4 columns. Then drag across the cells you want to merge (Content1 then Content2) and click "Merge".  That will give you the HTML and you can see how rowspan works.

Comment: Thank you for showing me this site :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below:

```
<table border=1>
<tr class='tableheader'>
    <td>Title 1</td>
    <td>Title 2</td>
    <td>Title 3</td>
    <td>Title 5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td rowspan="3">Content 1</td>
    <td rowspan="3">Content 2</td>
    <td>Content 3</td>
    <td>Content 5</td>
</tr>
<tr class='tableheader'>
    <td>Title 4</td>
    <td>Title 6</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Content 4</td>
    <td>Content 6</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

In your css, You can apply specific format for the class `tableheader` to differentiate the title rows clearly.

Comment: Thanks for also showing me the specific format for tableheader!

Answer (score 1):

Please don't abuse tables for layout tasks. You can easily achieve this layout with a couple of divs and CSS.

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="box double">
        <div class="title">Title 1</div>
        Content
    </div>
    <div class="box double">
        <div class="title">Title 2</div>
        Content
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="title">Title 3</div>
        Content
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="title">Title 4</div>
        Content
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="title">Title 5</div>
        Content
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="title">Title 6</div>
        Content
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    width: 400px;
}
.box {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
    background-color: red;
}
.double {
    height: 200px;
}
.title {
    background-color: green;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

[Demo on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZQcVt/)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Title 1</td>
        <td>Title 2</td>
        <td>Title 3</td>
        <td>Title 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="3">Content 1</td>
        <td rowspan="3">Content 2</td>
        <td>Content 3</td>
        <td>Content 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Title 4</td>
        <td>Title 6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Content 4</td>
        <td>Content 6</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```